# Java Method Pass-by-Value Issue

Tags: java

When I call my `bar(Map map)` method from my current `foo(...)` method, I run into the following behavior where bar() says that map is empty.

```
private void foo() {
  Map map = new Map(); // pseudocode
  // add (key, value)'s to map
  printMap(map); // prints key and values
  Map newMap = bar(map);
  ...
  System.out.println(newMap.size()); // returns 0  
} // end foo();

private Map bar(Map map) {
  printMap(map); // return empty
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**: Could it have been this print method's `it.remove()`call ? When I removed this call, I no longer had a problem.

```
private void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        logger.info(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Comment: If `printMap` is idempotent, you should not observe that behaviour => show your actual code.

Comment: post more code in `bar` method..what you doing in that method and what you return from that method ?

Comment: I do not see any entries being added to the map so why should it not be empty? Try to add, with existing code, the entries should show up.

Comment: Kevin, as it seems you do not store the returned value from printMap (altough logically it should be void as it states print) into any other Map type variable. It will be easier to help with the actual code

Comment: @kevin : indeed the reference of the `map` is passed by value but the memory location its pointing to is same. so if you pass a reference the value of reference is duplicated but they refer to same location so the changes in referred location reflects in the caller function too.

Comment: thanks. folks. silly error on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly remove items:

```
 it.remove();
```

Then you will have an empty list. Because you're passing `map` to the method by reference.

To handle exceptions, use `try/catch` block, or `throw` exception out.

To avoid concurrent modifying you should use synchronizing mechanisms.

Comment: He appears to be only using one thread.  He could use ConcurrentHashMap to allow concurrent access, but I believe the confusion is the believe the Map has been passed by value.

Comment: Exactly, I think your guess is right.

Answer (score 2):

A common confusion is to think of `Map` as an object, like it is in C++.  It is not.  It is a reference to an object.  This means when you pass your *reference by value*, only the reference is copied.  If you change this reference to another Map, this doesn't affect the caller.  However, if you access the reference and change the contents of the object, the caller can see this change.

In your case you are removing the entries of the map as you go and so when you return the caller see an empty Map.

BTW to print a map all you need do is

```
private void logMap(Map<?,?> map) {
    for(Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet())
        logger.info(entry); // logs; key = value
}
```